# what is autorelease frequency and target while creating dispatch queue?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

i was reading about dispatch queue creation method:

```
"DispatchQueue(label: <#T##String#>, 
qos: <#T##DispatchQoS#>, 
attributes: <#T##DispatchQueue.Attributes#>, 
autoreleaseFrequency: <#T##DispatchQueue.AutoreleaseFrequency#>, 
target: <#T##DispatchQueue?#>)"
```

but not able to clear exactly what does, autorelease frequency and target parameters explain ?

can you give me simple example which describes them ?

Answer (score 3):

Re autorelease frequency, see the [description of the possible values](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/autoreleasefrequency). It dictates when an autorelease pool is drained. An autorelease object is a type of memory management available in Objective-C (see [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)). But this is of diminished relevance in Swift, really only an issue if your Swift code is calling some Objective-C code that is creating autorelease objects, which is increasingly uncommon. And even if you are dealing with Objective-C autorelease objects, the default behavior is generally preferable. A substantive discussion of `autorelease` objects is probably beyond the scope of this question, but, in short, this parameter is rarely needed, especially not in Swift.

Re target queue, in [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch) when we specify that queue B has a target of queue A, that means that everything you dispatch to B will actually run on A behind the scenes. So, why would you do that? One scenario is that you want to avoid unnecessary context switches. See WWDC video [Modernizing Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/706/?time=1235), which talks about this feature. That link drops you 20:35 into that video, where they’re talking about target queues, but watch the whole video to put that conversation in perspective.

Bottom line, you rarely need either of these two parameters and are best omitted unless you need them for some very specific reason.

---

For more information, see the `init(label:qos:attributes:autoreleaseFrequency:target:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300059-init).